# remove any digit from a set in Java

Tags: java, set

I have a set in Java looks like

```
[0.99998945, line10Rule:14013, noOfCommits:0]
```

and, I want to remove all digital numbers and colon ':' from its element to get

```
[line10Rule, noOfCommits]
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What kind of set is this? What type of objects does it hold?

Comment: is your Set not generic ?? does your set restrict types ??

Comment: `:` is not a number and still you removed it. Please be more specific on the contents and what do you want to remove. If you have "10.23." what will be kept if anything is kept at all? How about negatives? What is expected for input `["semi-23final"]` is it `["semi-final"]` or `["semifinal"]`

Comment: I edited the question. So, I need to remove any digit number and ':'. For '10.23', it will be removed at all. Also, the string neither have negatives nor any other symbols other than ':'

Comment: what if it's not a number and does not contain a colon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("0.99998945", "line10Rule:14013", "noOfCommits:0"));
    ListIterator<String> i = list.listIterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String s = i.next();
        int p = s.indexOf(':');
        if (p > 0) {
            i.set(s.substring(0, p));
        } else {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

output

```
[line10Rule, noOfCommits]
```

Answer (score 2):

Now corrected:

```
String[] array = new String[set.size()];   // create a String array of the same size as the set
set.toArray(array);                        // copy the sets content into the array
set.clear();                               // clear the set

for (String string : array) {              // iterate through the array
    set.add(string.replaceAll("[0-9]*$", ""));   // remove the digits and put the resulting String back into the set    
}
```

@jlordo: thanks for pointing it out. I forgot, that the iterator works on a copy of the String. This may not be elegant (iterating through so many loops etc) but it works :D

regards  Christoph

Comment: So `replaceAll()` returns a new string...String is immutable.

Comment: @jlordo thanks for the effort of explaining :) I just corrected it

Comment: I just realized that copying the set into an array and then putting the result back into the set is one step too much, you can also create a second set and then iterate through the first one: for(String string : set1){ set2.add(string.replace....);}

Answer (score 0):

No way, you will have to recreate the set item by item. To replace numbers with "", consider String.replace().